# File google-services.json is missing error even if i Have the json in project

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, build

```
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\path...\gms_android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
  C:\Users\path...\gms_android\app\src\release\google-services.json
  C:\Users\path...\gms_android\app\src\nullnullRelease\google-services.json
  C:\Users\path...\gms_android\app\src\nullnull\release\google-services.json
  C:\Users\path...\gms_android\app\src\release\nullnull\google-services.json
  C:\Users\path...\gms_android\app\google-services.json
```

I have downloaded .json file and it;s location is here

[image]

It has been worked until now, and suddenly I started to get this error, not sure how to solve it

EDIT:
Forgot to mention I have tried several times invalidate cache & restrat, clean, rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `google-services.json` file in the app folder of the project ,try the following

cut the JSON  file from debug folder , and go to app folder , right click and paste there , it will be put in the app folder but not add to any sub folders

Comment: but i will have multiple  gson.files for many flavours

Comment: check this link it might help https://medium.com/@dev.amanchugh/how-to-use-a-google-services-json-file-for-different-build-variant-or-flavors-in-android-7c8949514819